# Unable to access internet Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns

I am unable to connect to internet from VirtualBox in Ubuntu -

Below is the nslookup commands I ran -

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ nslookup
> server 8.8.8.8
Default server: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
> www.google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
>
```

The /etc/resolv.conf file config -

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain informatica.com
search informatica.com cloudera
nameserver 10.65.32.40
nameserver 10.65.32.21
nameserver 10.65.32.113
```

Route table information

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.56.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
```

If Config details

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:F2:E7:D4  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4418 (4.3 KiB)  TX bytes:66630 (65.0 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:38:B8:48  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4836 (4.7 KiB)  TX bytes:1086 (1.0 KiB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:64:6B:6B  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:74423 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7074003 (6.7 MiB)  TX bytes:10944 (10.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:56596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:66442787 (63.3 MiB)  TX bytes:66442787 (63.3 MiB)
```

Please let me know how to resolve the issue

Output of ip r s

```
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 1 
192.168.56.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.56.0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1003 
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  proto static
```

Comment: yeh I was going to ask is your virtual-box using nat or bridge mode? do you want them to be on same ip segment or separate networks?

Answer (score 1):

What I can see is that you don't have any default gateway.

Add one related to your virtualbox:

```
sudo ip route add default via 10.0.2.2
```

then try the `ping`, `dig`, `nslookup`, etc:

```
$ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8

$ nslookup askubuntu.com
```

Also make sure that your VirtualBox configuration is correct.

Comment: When I ran the command I get below - [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo ip route add default via 10.0.2.2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Comment: Run this command and add the output to your question: `ip route show`.

Comment: Please find it below 10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15 
192.168.56.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.56.0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1003 
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  proto static

Comment: Run `sudo ifdown eth0; sudo ifup eth0` see what happens.

Comment: Here's the output - [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo ifdown eth0
Device state: 3 (disconnected)
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo ifup eth0
Active connection state: activating
Active connection path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
state: activated
Connection activated

Comment: I didn't want the output, after doing that your default gateway should be set... check if your network works or not, also check `ip r s` add the output to your question so it's more readable.

Comment: My desktop is on Wifi and I see that the virtualbox host only adapters are enables but no internet access showing in both IPV4 and IPV6 in networking center. In the VM it's showing all 3 adapters are wired connected and deactivated .These are wired connector ethernet.Is that the issue ? However I can ping to 8.8.8.8 but not to www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

All that you have to is reset the config file. This can be done in one line command

```
sudo ifdown eth0; sudo ifup eth0
```